# How to use OEM data to instead of TLE data?

Tags: python, pyorbital

I used TLE data to calculate stallite Latitude, Longitude, Altitude by pyorbital.orbital.Orbital as below

```
import pyorbital.orbital
orb = pyorbital.orbital.Orbital("ISS", line1=line1, line2=line2)
```

Now the data format is changed to OEM, I googled but I couldn't find any infomaion to use OEM data for stallite Latitude, Longitude, Altitude, does anyone give me some hint?